# "Avoid an excessive DOM size" How to reduce DOM size in react JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Im my react my when I test in PageSpeed and LightHouse getting this

[image]

How to reduce it?
if **react-window** will help me then how to use it in landing page?

Comment: The thing with vanilla ReactJs is that browser needs to load all logic in order to first render. You can decrease dom size by using frameworks like NextJs which separates logic of different page. (From what I know, I'm probably wrong)

Comment: You reduce it by not having over 4000 elements on the page at the same time I guess. What is on the page?

Comment: @Andy this is the landing page includes hero section, slider , accordion...etc

Comment: @YuvrajChaudhari landing page with 4000 elements? It doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Konrad Linkowski landing page means home page ("localhost:3000") 
if It doesn't seem right then what should I do?

Comment: Reduce the number of elements. Even facebook has 3000 elements when loaded only and it's bloated.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski bloated means?

Comment: @YuvrajChaudhari that is too many elements and it running really slow.
Can you show us your code? There is no way to help you without it.

Answer (score -2):

Generally, this error occurs when you try to write a lot of content in a single component. **Divide your application into multiple components** and **lazily load** those components depending on your specific need.

https://blog.bitsrc.io/lazy-loading-react-components-with-react-lazy-and-suspense-f05c4cfde10c

Comment: already divided into multiple components and lazy loaded